# SymmetricDS: Cleaning Staging Area

Tags: symmetricds

After skipping a row in a batch synchronisation the staging area should be cleaned. It is possible to do it manually. (https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_outgoing_batch_errors)

How can I clean it manually? Is it done by removing all contents from temp-directory of symmetricd?

Comment: please add some more info. the context is not clear and the link points to the ddl of the table conflict which isn’t related to the staging area. btw, what’s the ‘staging area’?

Comment: sry, it was the wrong link. This is the correct one: https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_outgoing_batch_errors

it's not about a concrete scenario. It's about cleaning the stage area after resolving the conflict manual by removing conficting data from batch. 

see last paragraph in 5.4.3: "After modifying the batch you will have to clear the Staging Area manually or wait for the staged version of the batch to timeout and clear itself."

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `stream.to.file.enabled` for the targeting node could be set to `false` before resolving the conflict. It would prevent symmetricDs using the local cache at all. After conflict resolution do not forget to set it to `true`.